# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown - SlideToggle Effect on Dropdown Menu Open and Close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I apply SlideToggle effect for Dropdown Menu from Bootstrap?

If I click on Dropdown it should slideDown, and clicking outside it should slideUp...

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0vjhaazv/1/)

---

> **HTML**

---

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this jquery  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/0vjhaazv/10/)**

```
     $('#ddl').click(function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
if ( $( "ul" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( "ul" ).show( "slow" );
    $("ul").addClass("ex");
  } 
    else {
    $( "ul" ).slideUp();
  }
});

$(window).on('click', function(e) {

     $( "ul" ).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but if I click outside, it is not getting closed :(

Comment: Hi @Shri, sorry... still not working... on clicking inside dropdown it is working fine... but I want the same when I click outside of Dropdown menu...

Comment: Try `$(window).on('click', ...` instead of `$('body').on('click', ...`